How can I plot a graph with layered structure with subgraphs within each layer?
I have a set of elements on which I defined a given relationship that allowed me to define a partial order on the set. I then introduced a second relationship to be applied to elements that were not comparable through the first relationship. This leads to a sort of layered graph where the nodes in each layer are not individual nodes, but instead subgraphs with multiple nodes, such that:

Each subgraph is in itself a layered graph (that could be represented with a Hasse diagram)
Connections between the top-level layers are only established between nodes of the top sublevel of a given subgraph and nodes of the bottom sublevel of a given subgraph of the next layer in the top-level hierarchy.
The entire graph should be symmetric around the Y axis

I guess it would end up being similar to a nested Hasse diagram. Is there any relatively straightforward way that I could plot this? Ideally, having control over how much weight (reflected in how much change in position along the Y axis) each order relationship has.
Here is a simplified example of the type of graph I mean:
H = nx.DiGraph()

H.add_node(0, A=0, B=0)
H.add_node(1, A=1, B=1)
H.add_node(2, A=1, B=1)
H.add_edge(0, 1)
H.add_edge(0, 2)
H.add_node(3, A=2, B=2)
H.add_node(4, A=2, B=2)
H.add_node(5, A=2, B=2)
H.add_node(6, A=2, B=2)
H.add_edge(1, 3)
H.add_edge(1, 4)
H.add_edge(2, 5)
H.add_edge(2, 6)
H.add_node(7, A=2, B=3)
H.add_node(8, A=2, B=3)
H.add_node(9, A=2, B=3)
H.add_node(10, A=2, B=3)
H.add_node(11, A=2, B=4)
H.add_node(12, A=2, B=4)
H.add_edge(3, 7)
H.add_edge(4, 8)
H.add_edge(5, 9)
H.add_edge(6, 10)
H.add_edge(7, 11)
H.add_edge(8, 11)
H.add_edge(9, 12)
H.add_edge(10, 12)
H.add_node(13, A=3, B=4)
H.add_node(14, A=3, B=4)
H.add_node(15, A=3, B=4)
H.add_node(16, A=3, B=4)
H.add_node(17, A=3, B=4)
H.add_node(18, A=3, B=4)
H.add_node(19, A=3, B=5)
H.add_node(20, A=3, B=5)
H.add_edge(11, 13)
H.add_edge(11, 14)
H.add_edge(11, 15)
H.add_edge(12, 16)
H.add_edge(12, 17)
H.add_edge(12, 18)
H.add_edge(14, 19)
H.add_edge(17, 20)
H.add_node(21, A=4, B=5)
H.add_edge(19, 21)
H.add_edge(20, 21)

In this example, I would like to use the values of attribute A to define the top-level layers, within which the clusters of nodes would be plotted with position along the Y axis being modulated through the value of B (but having a smaller impact than the modulation of the Y position done by the value of A). E.g., in the example, for A=2 there would be 2 clusters of nodes/subgraphs:

Nodes 3, 4, 7, 8 and 11
Nodes 5, 6, 9, 10 and 12

Applying pygraphviz's dot layout results in:
first_levels = {key: value["A"] for key, value in H.nodes(data=True)}
colors = [plt.cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, max(first_levels.values()) + 1))[first_levels[node]] for node in H.nodes()]
labels = {node: str(node) for node in H.nodes()}

pos = graphviz_layout(H, prog='dot')
pos = {node: (x, -y) for node, (x, y) in pos.items()}
nx.draw(H, pos, node_color=colors, labels=labels)


Nodes are colored by value of A. Note how this does not keep a nested layered structure, instead giving a new Y position for each combination of level-sublevel. This can be easily seen in that the difference in Y position between nodes with different color (e.g., same value of A) is the same as the difference in Y position between layers with nodes of the same color (which have the same value of A but different value of B).
I have made some attempts at roughly achieving my goal by taking the X positions calculated by dot layout and then adding custom Y positions.
pos_dot = graphviz_layout(H, prog='dot')

pos = {}

nodesDictionary = {}
for node in H.nodes(data=True):
    A_value = node[1]['A']
    B_value = node[1]['B']
    if A_value not in nodesDictionary:
        nodesDictionary[A_value] = {}
    if B_value not in nodesDictionary[A_value]:
        nodesDictionary[A_value][B_value] = []
    nodesDictionary[A_value][B_value].append(node)

min_A_value = min(nodesDictionary.keys())
max_A_value = max(nodesDictionary.keys())
min_B_values = [min(nodesDictionary[A_value].keys()) for A_value in nodesDictionary]
max_B_values = [max(nodesDictionary[A_value].keys()) for A_value in nodesDictionary]
ranges_B_values = [max_B_values - min_B_values for min_B_values, max_B_values in zip(min_B_values, max_B_values)]
max_range_B_values = max(ranges_B_values)
multiplier_Y_for_A_value = max_range_B_values*3
for A_value in nodesDictionary:
    max_B_value = max(nodesDictionary[A_value].keys())
    median_B_value = np.median(list(nodesDictionary[A_value].keys()))
    number_nodes_thisAvalue_minimum_B_value = len(nodesDictionary[A_value][min(nodesDictionary[A_value].keys())])
    for B_value in nodesDictionary[A_value]:
        for node in nodesDictionary[A_value][B_value]:
            y = A_value * multiplier_Y_for_A_value + B_value - median_B_value
            nodes_on_sublevel = sorted([n for n in H.nodes(data=True) if n[1]['A'] == A_value and n[1]['B'] == B_value], key=lambda s: s[1]['B'])
            x = pos_dot[node[0]][0]
            pos[node[0]] = (x, y)

nx.draw(H, pos, node_color=colors, labels=labels, node_size=90)

This results in the following:

While this is not perfect, it shows what my goal would be: the Y position is mostly determined by the value of property A (which is calculated as a consequence of the top-level ordering relationship), with the value of property B (calculated through the second ordering relationship) adding smaller adjustments to the rough value determined already by property A.
It should be noted that for larger graphs, the X positions output by dot do not necessarily result in a plot symmetric around the Y axis. Also, ideally, the subgraphs defined by each connected components for all nodes with a given A value would also be symmetric around their own local Y axis.

Code to produce a [mre] of the graph and a mockup of potential expected visualizations would improve your question

Just did it! Hopefully it's clearer now :)

More clear, but I'm easily confused.  What is "wrong" with the above graph?

Just added my rough attempt at getting something close to what I had in mind!

Again, what is sub-optimal with your program's result?    p.s. Why use  dot at all?  Maybe just position all the nodes programmatically, then use neato -n to add the edges (https://graphviz.org/faq/#FaqDotWithNodeCoords)

Well, with my implementation I just took the X values from those directly calculated with dot, as I have not figured out what would be the optimal way to get X positions. While for this particular case it resulted in a symmetric plot, for more complex graphs that should still be symmetric, it does not necessarily yield a symmetric plot. And my implementation does not scale greatly when adding lots of nodes, so I was wondering if there was a cleaner solution that also minimizes the number of edge crossings.

[I only roughly understand what this is about, but my intuition is that you may need to do the X positioning yourself]  For symmetric output based on asymmetric input,  consider adding invisible nodes to the dot input, to make the dot result symmetric.  Again. neato -n might help minimize edge crossings (set splines=true)

Not sure if this helps at all, but this is a straight dot graph that seems to approach yours.
digraph HH{
rankdir=BT
ordering=out
nodesep=.8

0 -> 1
0 -> 2
1 -> 3
1 -> 4
2 -> 5
2 -> 6
3 -> 7
4 -> 8
5 -> 9
6 -> 10
7 -> 11
8 -> 11
9 -> 12
10 -> 12
11 -> 13
11 -> 14
11 -> 15
12 -> 16
12 -> 17
12 -> 18
14 -> 19
17 -> 20
19 -> 21
20 -> 21

{ node[group=g100] 0 21}
{ node[group=g101] 2 5 9 16 20}
{ node[group=g103] 6 10 12 17}
{ node[group=g104] 18}
{ node[group=g99]  1 4 8 15 19}
{ node[group=g97]  3 7 11 14}
{ node[group=g96]  13}
}

Giving:


Thanks! However, this has the same problem as my straight application of dot, which is that it does not group the nodes with the same value for attribute A but different values of B closer than nodes with different value for attribute B
